# Do the series $\sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{e^{3k\mathrm{log}(k)}}{(k!)^2}$ and $\sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(k+1)^{k^2}}{k^{k^2}4^k}$ converge/diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a question about the following two series:
$$
G := \sum^\infty_{k=1} \frac{(k+1)^{k^2}}{k^{k^2}4^k}
$$
and
$$
L := \sum^\infty_{k=0} \frac{e^{3k\mathrm{log}(k)}}{(k!)^2}.
$$
For $G$ I tried using the root test:
$$
\sqrt[k]{\frac{(k+1)^{k^2}}{k^{k^2}4^k}} = \frac{(k+1)^k}{4k^k} \to \infty > 1.
$$
My question here is if what I did is enough to conclude that $G$ diverges or not. My idea was that in the last fraction $(k+1)^k$ grows much faster than just $k^k$ and thus the whole thing tends to infinity but I am not sure if it is okay to conclude that in this rather intuitive way.
For $L$ I also tried using the root test and got
$$
\sqrt[k]{\frac{e^{3k\mathrm{log}(k)}}{(k!)^2}} = \frac{e^{3\mathrm{log}(k)}}{\sqrt[k]{(k!)^2}} = e^3\frac{k}{\sqrt[k]{k!}\sqrt[k]{k!}}
$$
but I have no idea how I can simplify this expression further to "see" what value it approaches as $k \to \infty$. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Do you know Stirling approximation?

Comment: $\frac{(k+1)^k}{4k^k}=\frac 1 4 (1+\frac 1 k)^{k}\to \frac e  4<1$ so G converges.

Comment: @SineoftheTime I've come across it a couple of times but I shouldn't need to use it since it didn't yet officially occur in my lectures...

Comment: @geetha290krm How did you come up with this factorization? I guess Cactus did the same "trick" but after playing a little bit more with the term I still don't get it (I understand how we can get to $e^{k\mathrm{ln}(1+1/k)}$ though).

Comment: Nevermind... I got it. Sorry for the disturbance.

Answer (score -1):

For $G$, you made a mistake in the computation of the limit. Indeed, as said @geetha290krm,
$$
\frac{(k + 1)^k}{k^k} = e^{k\ln(1 + 1/k)} \rightarrow e,
$$
because $\ln(1 + x) = x + \mathrm{o}(x)$ when $x \rightarrow 0$. Hence, $G$ is a convergent series because $\frac{e}{4} < 1$. In fact, it shows that $(k + 1)^k$ doesn't grow much faster than $k^k$, it only grows about $e$ times faster. You must be careful that in limit calculus, $1^{+\infty}$ is an indeterminate form.

For the second one, you can use Stirling formula but it is not necessary. Indeed, the only thing you have to know is that for all $k \geqslant 1$, $k^k \geqslant k!$ (the ratio even diverges toward infinity) because,
$$
k^k = k \times k \times \cdots \times k \geqslant 1 \times 2 \times \cdots \times k = k!
$$
Therefore, (I assume the logarithm is natural),
$$
\frac{e^{3k\ln(k)}}{k!^2} = \frac{(k^k)^3}{k!^2} \geqslant \left(\frac{k^k}{k!}\right)^2 \geqslant 1.
$$
It implies that $L$ diverges. Be careful also, $e^{3\ln(k)} = k^3$ and not $e^3k$.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but I do not understand how $e^{k\mathrm{ln}(1+1/k)} \to e$ for $k \to \infty$. Could you elaborate further?

Comment: Because as far as I understand we get an undefined expression like $e^{\infty \cdot 0}$.

Comment: @FelixGervasi $\lim_{k\to \infty}e^{k\log(1+1/k)}=\lim_{j\to 0}e^{\frac{\log(1+j)}j}$

Comment: Okay I understood why $G$ converges by now. What I still don't understand is why $L$ diverges. How does $\frac{e^{3k\mathrm{ln}(k)}}{k!^2} \geq 1$ imply this?

Comment: A series of terms that don't converge toward $0$ diverges.